# Duo Security Auth

Tags: python, bash, api, python-requests, hmac

Trying to auth to Duo Security admin API but stuck in their way of authenticating. Reference: https://duo.com/docs/adminapi#authentication

They have a function that says it would be used to construct the “Authorization” and “Date” headers. Does anyone know how to go about getting this started?

```
import base64, email, hmac, hashlib, urllib

def sign(method, host, path, params, skey, ikey):
    """
    Return HTTP Basic Authentication ("Authorization" and "Date") headers.
    method, host, path: strings from request
    params: dict of request parameters
    skey: secret key
    ikey: integration key
    """

    # create canonical string
    now = email.Utils.formatdate()
    canon = [now, method.upper(), host.lower(), path]
    args = []
    for key in sorted(params.keys()):
        val = params[key]
        if isinstance(val, unicode):
            val = val.encode("utf-8")
        args.append(
            '%s=%s' % (urllib.quote(key, '~'), urllib.quote(val, '~')))
    canon.append('&'.join(args))
    canon = '\n'.join(canon)

    # sign canonical string
    sig = hmac.new(skey, canon, hashlib.sha1)
    auth = '%s:%s' % (ikey, sig.hexdigest())

    # return headers
    return {'Date': now, 'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode(auth)}
```

Comment: Getting what started? Are you asking how to call this function? How to include its results when doing a HTTP request? If it's the latter, can you show us how you're doing your HTTP requests *now*? Are you using the `requests` library? `urllib`? Something else?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm a novice at python. I thought that this function would be used in generating the proper formatted headers for the API. I would like to call the function to actually generate the headers. Just not sure where the integrated key and secret key would go.

Comment: It returns a dictionary of extra fields to be included in your request's headers, yes. `skey` and `ikey` -- the last two parameters -- are presumably your "integrated key" and "secret key". Is that the whole of your question?